# Control USB devices with udev and custom program

Tags: linux, udev

I have a script at `/tmp/udev_test.py` which gets executed with every USB device attached or detached, using this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/tmp/udev_test.py"
```

The script runs, and saves its environment into some file, and everything's OK.

Is there a way to control what USB devices recognized by system using this script?

I tried `exit(100)` at the end of script, but that didn't prevent attaching.

I googled, but found nothing useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

Seems no one knows, or is not willing to share.

Here is what I did.

Your program gets an environmental variable `$DEVPATH` and you should deauthorize the device with this path.

Here is an example of deauthorizing a device:

```
echo 0 > /sys$DEVPATH/authorized
```